# Toggle colour link colour on click

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a program where a series of labels are shown and each time you click on them, they appear within a div (`<div id = "div1"> </ div>`), and to remove the labels, you must return to click but this time on the labels that have appeared inside div1.

What I'm trying now is that every time I click on the labels outside the div1, they turn blue and if I delete them from div1, they go back to the same color they were.

Can you help me? Can i do it in html + css? or i need js?

This is my JS:

```
var ar = new Array();

function myFunction(tagName, tagId) {
    if (!document.getElementById(tagName)) {
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML +=
            '<label class="tags" id="' + tagName + '" onclick="rem(\'' + tagName + '\', \'' + tagId+ '\')">' + tagName + ',  </label>';

        ar.push(tagId);
        document.getElementById("hiddenfield").value = ar;
    }
}

function rem(tagName, tagId) {
    document.getElementById(tagName).remove();
    ar.splice(ar.indexOf(tagId), 1);
    document.getElementById("hiddenfield").value = ar;
}
```

This is my PHP:

```
<p>
    Introduce tags:
</p>

<div id="div1">
</div>
<h3>
    <?php
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<label><a class=\"trigger blue lighten-4\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#conditionModal\" onclick=\"myFunction('" . $row["tag_name"] ."', '" . $row["tag_id"] ."')\">" . $row["tag_name"] ." </a></label>";
    }
    ?>
</h3>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.trigger {
    padding: 1px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    color: #212121;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: red;/* #e6e6e6 */
}
/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: white;
}

.tags {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding: 1px 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    color: #212121;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px 5px;
}

.tags:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

What I would like is something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/L6VqK/

But instead of clicking the same link, the link is inside Div1

Comment: `#div1 label { color: blue; }` …?

Comment: Unless you want to have the servers PHP do the rerendering, you'll need JS, as you show yourself, to remove/recreate HTML nodes on the page. Are you stuck anywhere? Since you just need to do the opposite to move the labels back into the div.

Comment: @shilly The colour I would like to change from the labels if I make the first click is found in <h3> and then it appears in <div1>. To remove from <div1> I click again but inside <div1> and that's when the label that is inside <h3> should return to its color

Comment: @04FS this doesn't work I tried it :/

Comment: The coloring is just css, as 04FS shows. Remove `background-color: aliceblue;` and put it on the wrappers. So `#div1 .tags { background-color: aliceblue; }` and  after adding the id 'header' to the <h3>, `#header .tags { background-color: grey; }`. That way you do not have to change classes on the tags. Their container (either the div or the h3 ) determines their color.

Comment: The blue color probably comes from the class `blue` (_bad_ class name btw., because it is named after the _currently_ desired styling) you put on the `a` elements inside the labels, so you would have to format those to begin with – `#div1 label a`. If that still doesn’t work, then you might need to increase the specificity of your selector (how exactly, we can only guess, because the code you have shown doesn’t appear to contain the rule where the blue color actually comes from - `#div1 label a.blue` might do it then.)

Answer (score 1):

These are the basics. Just have two elements containing your labels. ( I use a list here, since it makes sense to use a list when listing multiple items. ) Then have the color be determined by the list they belong to, instead of having the color on the items themselves.

Switching from one list to the other is as easy as just appending the target to the new list.

```js
const tags = [ ...document.querySelectorAll( '.tag' )];
const input = document.querySelector( '#tags_input' );
const output = document.querySelector( '#tags_output' );
const move = event => {
  const list = event.target.parentNode.parentNode;
  if ( list.id === 'tags_input' ) output.appendChild( event.target.parentNode );
  else if ( list.id === 'tags_output' ) input.appendChild( event.target.parentNode );
};
tags.forEach( tag => tag.addEventListener( 'click', move ));
```

```css
#tags_input .tag {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#tags_output .tag {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tags_input">
  <li class="tag"><a href="#">First tag</a></li>
  <li class="tag"><a href="#">Second tag</a></li>
  <li class="tag"><a href="#">Third tag</a></li>
  <li class="tag"><a href="#">Fourth tag</a></li>
  <li class="tag"><a href="#">Fifth tag</a></li>
  <li class="tag"><a href="#">Sixth tag</a></li>
  <li class="tag"><a href="#">Seventh tag</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="tags_output"></ul>
```

Keep in mind that this is very similar to basic link functionality, where already clicked links use the :visited color, which can be fully done in CSS ( by using a:visited, a:hover, a:active, etc ).

It's only moving the items and resetting the link color back to the original , as if the link is not clicked yet, that cannot be fully done in CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, maybe I should do it this way. Do you know how to make the labels return to the same position where they were when clicking on 'tags_output' again?

Comment: @ana , yes, but the the JS structure becomes a little more complicated if you want to do it 'efficiently'. Is that ok?

Comment: Hmm, still got a bug to fix. I'll try to update my answer tomorrow.